# Unable to solve Cordova's SQlite error: Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I just started to learn Cordova and is currently learning SQLite with https://www.toptal.com/mobile/developing-mobile-applications-with-apache-cordova . However, I'm getting the following error with my new Cordova project. I've pasted the sample code where the error occured, but I have no clue and can't find the problem since I can't find the problem in the code. I've also added the correct SQlite plugin for cordova. I would love to hear from you.

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefined
        at new SQLiteStorageService (SQLiteStorageService.js:3)
        at Object.initialize (Controller.js:13)
        at new Controller (Controller.js:68)
        at Object.onDeviceReady (index.js:33)
        at Object.initialize (index.js:27)
        at index.js:36
```

Controller.js

```
var Controller = function() {
    var controller = {
        self: null,
        initialize: function() {
            self = this;
            new SQLiteStorageService().done(function(service){
                self.storageService = service;
                self.bindEvents();
                //render search view after storage service is initialized.
                 self.renderSearchView(); 
            }).fail(function(error){
               alert(error); 
            });


        },

        bindEvents: function() {
            $('.tab-button').on('click', this.onTabClick);
        },

        onTabClick: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                return;
            }

            var tab = $(this).data('tab');
            if (tab === '#add-tab') {
                self.renderPostView();
            } else {
                self.renderSearchView();
            }
        },

        renderPostView: function() {
            $('.tab-button').removeClass('active');
            $('#post-tab-button').addClass('active');

            var $tab = $('#tab-content');
            $tab.empty();
            $("#tab-content").load("./views/post-project-view.html", function(data) {
                $('#tab-content').find('#post-project-form').on('submit', self.postProject);
            }); 
        },

        renderSearchView: function() {
            $('.tab-button').removeClass('active');
            $('#search-tab-button').addClass('active');

            var $tab = $('#tab-content');
            $tab.empty();

            var $projectTemplate = null;
            $("#tab-content").load("./views/search-project-view.html", function(data) {
                $projectTemplate = $('.project').remove();
                // Load projects here
            }); 
        }
    }
    controller.initialize();
    return controller;
}
```

SQLiteStorageService.js

```
SQLiteStorageService = function () {
    var service = {};
    var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "demo.toptal",location:"default"});

    service.initialize = function() {

        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql(
                'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS projects ' + 
                '(id integer primary key, name text, company text, description text, latitude real, longitude real)'
            ,[], function(tx, res) {
                tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM projects', [], function(tx, res) {
                    deferred.resolve(service);
                }, function(tx, res) {
                    deferred.reject('Error initializing database');
                });
            }, function(tx, res) {
                deferred.reject('Error initializing database');
            });
        });
        return deferred.promise();
    }

    service.getProjects = function() {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();

        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM projects', [], function(tx, res) {

                var projects = [];
                console.log(res.rows.length);
                for(var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
                    var project = { name: res.rows.item(i).name, company: res.rows.item(i).company, description: res.rows.item(i).description };
                    if (res.rows.item(i).latitude && res.rows.item(i).longitude) {
                        project.location = {
                            latitude: res.rows.item(i).latitude,
                            longitude: res.rows.item(i).longitude
                        }
                    } 
                    projects.push(project);
                }
                deferred.resolve(projects);

            }, function(e) {
                deferred.reject(e);
            });
        });
        return deferred.promise();
    }

    service.addProject = function(name, company, description, addLocation) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        console.log(db);
        if (addLocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (
                function(position) {
                    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
                    var lon = position.coords.longitude;

                    db.transaction(
                        function(tx) {
                            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO projects (name, company, description, latitude, longitude) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', 
                                [name, company, description, lat, lon], 
                                function(tx, res) 
                            {
                                console.log('success');
                                deferred.resolve();
                            }, function(e) 
                            {
                                console.log('failure');
                                deferred.reject('Error posting a new project');
                            });
                        },
                        function() {
                            deferred.reject('Error during save process. ');
                        }
                    );
                },
                function() {
                    deferred.reject(
                            'We could not fetch your current location. ' + 
                            'Please try again or post a project without adding a location');
                },
                {maximumAge: 60000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true}
            );
        } else {
            db.transaction(function(tx) {
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO projects (name, company, description) VALUES (?,?,?)', [name, company, description], function(tx, res) {
                    deferred.resolve();
                }, function(e) {
                    deferred.reject(e);
                });
            });
        }
        return deferred.promise();
    }

    return service.initialize();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the plugin is not added to your project. You can execute following command at the root folder of your project and add the plugin

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage.git
```

This will add plugin to your cordova project and make the wrapper object available in script. More details can be found at [ngcordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/sqlite/).

Comment: I checked it and it is installed. Should I use $cordovaSQLite.openDB instead of window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase?

Comment: You can do that, if you are building App using AngularJS in cordova. Otherwise, you can use `sqlitePlugin` object. In such case, make sure, your code is accessing the object after `deviceready` event is fired.